# C2440 return cannot convert from 'string' to 'string *'

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have been struggling to understand why I cannot return a string pointer from this method. I need to return a pointer and not just a string from this method as it is part of a linked list assignment. How can I do this?

**Here's the method:**

```
std::string* lookupRec(Node* currentNode, std::string key)
{


    if (currentNode != nullptr)
    {
        // If key == nodes key then that nodes item will be returned
        if (currentNode->key == key)
        {
            // ERROR: cannot convert from 'string' to 'string *'
            return currentNode->item;

        }
        else
        {
            return lookupRec(currentNode->ptrNext, key);

        }
    }

    return nullptr;

}
```

Comment: Perhaps in this case you might want to do some research about [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

Comment: `return &currentNode->item;`

Comment: Thank you guys - return &currentNode->item; worked!

Answer (score 2):

Use `return &currentNode->item;`. Without the `&`, the compiler tries to *copy* the string and return the copy. With the `&`, the address of the string is returned as a pointer. Note that this is equal to `return &(currentNode->item);`, i.e. the `&` automatically refers to the whole expression, not just `currentNode` (i.e. `->` takes precedence over `&`).

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you attach implementation of your 'Node' structure.

If the Node.item is type of `std::string`, you can use:

```
return &currentNode->item;
```

instead of just `currentNode->item`.